# losing the scope of an object inside an included file

Tags: php, class, oop, object, static

Am trying to call an object's method inside of an included file which the included file itself, was loaded in the class with output buffer like below:

```
public function render($file){

    ob_start();
    require_once($file);
    $this->template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $this->template;
}
```

Getting these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: template
Fatal error: Call to a member function showTitle() on a non-object
```

The included file is to be used as a template and there will be many. It works fine when used as `static` property and method set, but not with the instantiated object's property and method set which is the required way.

Below are all test files for your review.

Class file "classTest.php":

```
<?php
    // classTest.php

    class Test{

    protected $template;
    protected $title =  "Title";
    static    $titleStatic = "Title Static";

    public function render($file){

        ob_start();
        require_once($file);
        $this->template = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $this->template;
    }

    public function showTitle(){
        return $this->title;
    }

    static function showTitleStatic(){
        return self::$titleStatic;

    }
}
?>
```

Test file "test.php":

```
<?php
    // test.php

    require_once 'classTest.php';

    $template = new Test;

    echo $template->showTitle();

    $templateFile = 'includeTest.php';

    echo $template->render($templateFile);

?>
```

Include file "includeTest.php":

```
<!--    includeTest.php     -->

<div id="container">
    <div id="titleStatic"><?php echo Test::showTitleStatic(); ?></div>
    <div id="title"><?php echo $template->showTitle(); ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your includeTest.php to this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="titleStatic"><?php echo Test::showTitleStatic(); ?></div>
    <div id="title"><?php echo $this->showTitle(); ?></div>
</div>
```

Your calling $template when it should be $this since it's being populated inside the class not from outside.